# Menu char input to int

Tags: c++

I'm working on something along the lines of a console based Tamagotchi (I can't draw, so I'm working with what I've got). For my menu functions, I'm trying to present a menu > take in user input as a char > convert the char to an int > perform selection.

```
#include <iostream>

//Functions
void menuShow();
int menuChoice();
void menuAction();

int main()
{
    menuAction();
}


//Menu display
void menuShow()
{
    std::cout << "\nPlease choose from the following:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(S)tatus of your pet." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(F)eed your pet." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(Q)uit." << std::endl;
}

//Convert input from char to int
int menuChoice()
{
    char userChoice;
    int convertChoice = 0;

    do
    {
        menuShow();
        std::cout << "Choice: ";
        std::cin >> userChoice;
        if ((userChoice = 'S') || (userChoice = 's'))
        {
            convertChoice = 1;
        }

        else if ((userChoice = 'F') || (userChoice = 'f'))
        {
            convertChoice = 2;
        }

        else if ((userChoice = 'Q') || (userChoice = 'q'))
        {
            convertChoice = 3;
        }

    } while ((userChoice != 'S') || (userChoice != 's') || (userChoice != 'F') || (userChoice != 'f') || (userChoice != 'Q') || (userChoice != 'q'));    //Repeat if incorrect selection is made

    return convertChoice;    //return converted int
}

//Get converted choice and perform related action
void menuAction()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        choice = menuChoice();    //initialize using returned convertChoice
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "You look at your pets' stats" << std::endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            std::cout << "You feed your pet" << std::endl;
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "You have quit!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
}
```

As of right now it doesn't accept an input and perform the action, it just spits out the menu over and over. **So my questions are:** 1) Am I on the right track for this conversion to work or am I not even close? 2) If I'm way off, can you push me in the right direction (given that this is possible)?

Also, I know this could be taken care of by using int's for the user selections and passed to the switch. However, I wanted to see if I could do this for future reference, as well as try to think "outside the box" in terms of the repetitive "option 1:", option 2:", etc.

Comment: When you used the debugger, what happened when you executed each statement, one at a time (called single stepping)?

Comment: Please convert the `choice` variable to either lower case or upper case before comparing.  See std::tolower and std::toupper.

Comment: You might take a look at using a `switch` for tha input too. And using early-`return` (or maybe `break`) might help you avoid repeating yourself with such a long and error-prone loop-condition.

Comment: You could use a `break` statement inside the `if` statements to exit the loop.

Comment: Why are you converting the choices to numbers?  You could skip that step and process them by letter.  The `switch` statement works with characters too.

Comment: Yup I'm an idiot. I tried using the switch on the chars before, but apparently my syntax was wrong or something because I was a few errors and the descriptions made it seem like it wasn't possible. The breaks helped with what I was initially trying to do though. Also, thanks for the suggestion about tolower, I hadn't thought about using that. Thank you!